# Understanding topological divisor of zero

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I am reading [this paper](http://operator.pmf.ni.ac.rs/licne_prezentacije/DDjordjevic/publications/iterative-outer.pdf) also [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300306015840) where in the **Theorem 2.1** term topological divisor of zero has been used. I have gone through wiki articles where it has been mentioned that

An element $z$ of a Banach algebra $A$ is called a topological divisor of zero if there exists a sequence $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, ... of elements of $A$ such that
the sequence $zx_n$ converges to the zero element, but
the sequence $x_n$ does not converge to the zero element.

However, I am not able to apply this definition in the paper mentioned above. Is there any other definitions of topological divisor of zero? 
Please explain me about this term so that I can understand why author of the paper has used this term?

Please help and thanks for all.

Comment: Is their an example of a topological zero divisor that is not a zero divisor?

Answer (score 5):

If your Banach algebra $A$ is the algebra $\mathcal L(E)$ of all bounded linear operators on some Banach space $E$, then one can use the following characterization: an operator $T\in\mathcal L(E)$ is $not$ a right topological divisor of $0$ if and only if $T$ is one-to-one with closed range; equivalently, if there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\Vert Tx\Vert\geq c\Vert x\Vert$ for all $x\in E$.

I don't know if this helps!

Comment: I wanted help in the context of the paper given in the link.

Comment: I think there is a misleading statement in Theorem 2.1. What the author wanted to say (I hope) is that an operator $T$ is not a right topological divisor of $0$ if and only if the $adjoint\; operator$ $T'$ is onto.